# iOS App Rejected because of settings redirection

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval

I have a 'Click to go settings' button if I Click on that It redirects to `Settings -> General ->  Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Inside Keyboard`  app I released the version 1.0,But In the updated version apple rejected because of this.I thought they told to open `Setting -> General ->  Keyboard -> Keyboards` not to open deeply Is it right?
Any Help on this,I attached the screenshot for the app rejection:

[image]

Comment: did you used the custom keyboard..?

Comment: submit your queries to apple team..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik,Ok Thanks bro

Comment: @ShangariC. Did this "@"App-Prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard"" solve your problem?